# How to train an echo state network

Tags: neural-network

I f have a time series of long time horizon (like a stock price), how do I train in the simplest way the echo state network?

If I chose the training set to be 2 years e.g. then I could chose every day in those 2 years as input.

Can I train the network for 1 month? So i divide the 2 years in parts of 1 month. And for every month in the past I train the network and do average of all neworks?

So, waht are common methods for time series analysis with echo state networks for training? Do I rather train the whole time series or do I divide it supparts to train?